# Conversion types JNI JAVA

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I'm trying to use jni to call native functions in c++. All throughout the code there are

```
const void* 
void **
```

I researched online and the java equivalent would be just Object type. However I'm confused what to pass in as an parameter when calling these function in c++. Object type really can't store anything so I'm a bit confused.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to know what those `void*` will actually be in your C++ code.  They can't stay `void*` without them being converted or casted to a real type somewhere in your C++ code.

Comment: okay thanks. I'll look into that

Comment: As long as it is an opaque pointer you can use a long integer to hold that value.

Answer (score 1):

As pointer lengths are not fixed across different platforms, this question is not as trivial as it sounds.

Three ways to consider :

- Use a Java long ( a jlong in JNI ) which is 64-bits.  This assumes no one ever needs a pointer longer than 64-bits, which is a controversy I'm happy to avoid. :-)  Not strictly portable but *probably* safe ( for a while ).
- Use an array ( in Java ) to store the required pointer.  So your JNI code would create a jbyteArray of length sizeof(void *) and your Java code would handle a byte[], and you'd copy the pointer value into that array.  This is safe and portable as long as your Java code doesn't start mucking around with the array values ( which would be silly ).  As an aside I would suggest taking a *global ref* of the jbyteArray as you typically need to maintain some record of that pointer value for later disposal by the C/C++ side of things, so you need to prevent Java from garbage collecting it ( by taking a reference ).
- Lastly let your C/C++ code manage a hash table ( or similar ) mappings handles to maps.  The handles can be e.g. Java int types ( 32 bits on both the C/C++ and Java sides ), and the length of the pointers is the JNI code's problem.  Advantage is abstraction and portability.  Disadvantage is complexity ( unless you've C/C++ hash table code lying around to use ).  The persistence of that mapping data is also an issue.